# What threats can come from an outdated Certificate in a private LAN

Tags: certificates

In our company, we use a LAN "about 1,000 users", served with internal servers including email, DNS, and many web servers.
Whenever I access any of the network sites, I receive a message about an outdated certificate. When I spoke with their network admin, he said it's OK to add an exception to my browser and go on.

I'm aware of a potential MITM attacks, but as a normal user, what should I do to secure my privacy, specially that many of those sites are for financial business.

thanks.

Comment: For one, training someone to add exceptions is bad because then he/she might easier overlook when the certificate is from a MITM.

Comment: agreed, but without adding the exception I can't access any site, and the network admin is denying adding an up to date certs.

Comment: By "outdated" you mean "expired"?

Comment: Yes. about a year ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [X.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) certificate has several uses in the context of web browsing, among others the ability:

- for the **client** (user) to check with a "trusted" entity that they indeed release that certificate to the server claiming so. This check is quite subjective (and somehow less for [Extended Validation Certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate)) but there is nothing better as of now.
- for the **server** to check the connecting client. This is rarely used for "human" browsing but is common (or at least more used) for server to server communication

You can use either of them, or none - but what will always be in place  is a secure, encrypted tunnel between your browser and the target server.

This means that if you know somehow that the server you are targeting is the right one you could discard alerts from the browser. They just inform you that what you connect to is not what is claimed to be by the certificate, or that this information has not been checked by an third party (you both trust). The technical security of the connection (encryption) is not affected.

The expiration of a certificate (or incorrectness of other information it holds) invalidates its "trustfulness" but not the encryption part. Your connection is still secure. If the certificate itself was insecure (tempered with for instance) then you could not set up a connection at all.

Comment: "The expiration of a certificate invalidates its "trustfulness" but not the encryption part" ... that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An expired certificate does not necessarily mean that it's dangerous. To me, there are three main reasons for having expiry dates on certs:

1. If an attacker was trying to break the signature on the cert and make a fake cert, that's the minimum amount of time they's need if they threw lots of money at the breaking it.
2. In order to keep database sizes from growing uncontrollably, most [Certificate Authorities (CAs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) don't track revocation information for expired certs. That means that if the cert ever does get hacked, there's no way for you or your browser to find out.
3. So the CA that issued the cert can charge your company for a new cert every year.

**Bottom Line:** Unless your company's internal servers are a big juicy target for hackers, you're *probably* ok to keep trusting the expired cert. That said, before adding an exception, do due diligence and look at the certificate in your browser and make sure that 1) the site or sever it was *issued to* makes sense for your company, and 2) the CA that is was *issued from* is the same one that your company uses (ask your IT people).

[image]